# Ask hard questions on the Moderator Questionnaire

Tags: discussion, moderation, election, nominations

The Stack Exchange Moderator Questionnaire is a routine part of the election process. It's a way for the community to gauge the candidates' fitness for the job; for voters to read a bit into who people are, their role on the site, and the value they can bring to their community.

These questions aren't usually very hard. Here are some sample questions that commonly appear across the network:

> 1. As a moderator, your votes are binding - close, delete, tag synonyms, etc. How will this change how you usually VTC/VTD?
> 2. How much time do you think that you will be able to spend actively moderating every day? What is your usual activity pattern over the week?
> 3. With the diamond attached to everything you've said in the past, do you think you have represented the ideals of this community? And will you continue to do so in the future as you are held to a slightly higher/different standard?
> 4. etc. etc.

These questions are pulled in part from a short Stack template, and in part from community generation. But truthfully, these questions are painfully easy, and communities tend not to ask questions of substance. Most people we would seriously consider for the job *already know* how to do basic site cleanup actions properly. Once we vaguely know someone is viable for the role, all we're checking off with these questions is: can a moderator speak the correct words? does a moderator vaguely know a policy? And that's not useful information.

What we really need are *hard* questions: ones that show us the substance of our community leaders' character. What I'm proposing is a fundamental alteration to the way we go about asking our candidates questions, and the way we select people who are eligible for the role.

**I'd really like to see more difficult questions asked of the people we expect to lead us.** Some examples:

> 1. A user of a minoritized group tells you that a certain behavior is harmful for them, but it's not a behavior you've ever thought of as harmful in the past. How do you approach the situation, and how would you have that conversation?
> 2. When a user exhibits behavior symptomatic of bigotry, even if that behavior is subtle, to what extent do you place faith in the correctional process' ability to mitigate their behavior (mod messages, suspensions, etc.)? Do you believe you have the ability to help guide them out of that situation? And, what role do you see yourself playing in that conversation?
> 3. A user you normally think of as calm and collected is angry and causing disruption to the site. You're originally unsure why, but when you look into what happened, it seems like someone else's actions have upset them for reasons you think are understandable. However, the person who caused harm is quiet now, and doesn't appear to be causing further damage at the moment. How do you handle the situation? Who do you talk to, and what do you say?
> 4. Do you believe your role is to bring civility, peace, or justice to disputes on your site? Do you believe these aims can ever come in conflict, and if so, how would you resolve the discrepancy between them?
> 5. What is a memorable moment in which you let down someone who looks up to you? How did you make amends, and how did you give the situation closure?

In essence, I'd like to see the default template provided for moderator questionnaires ask questions that reveal more about the character of the people we are voting on -- not just their ability to use the site tools. They don't all need to be these kinds of questions, and whether these are default/filler I'm leaving open for now. I'm of the personal opinion that there should be a healthy mix of default and filler hard-questions, and classic mod-role questions.

These specific questions are just me spitballing ideas, and I'm totally open to other ones, or more thoughts on the topic.

Comment: I agree with the sentiments here. The current questions are focused on the janitorial role of moderators and not necessarily the community building aspects of the role. Moderators should be able to address both parts of the role in a manner that satisfies the community, so both types of questions need to be on the questionnaire.

Comment: These are good, so many of the questionnaires reveal so little.

Comment: FWIW, I have in the past proposed questions in these things based on scenarios or issues that I *know* the moderators on a site have faced or will be facing. These are hard. But they're hard precisely because there's no way to answer them with a pat response: the folks on the site will immediately know what I'm referring to and any attempt to hand-wave ("I will consult with my team and decide appropriately") will be scoffed at. By the same token, I suspect you perceive the standard questions as easy *because* they've been answered so many times: you already know the "correct" answers.

Comment: Certainly an idea worth considering, but your questions are pointed towards specific answers that are "desirable". Leading questions are problematic.

Comment: @Shog9 That's a trickier situation, I think. Referring to real events that have happened is always going to stir up old feelings. One line of defense against that is to make the questions more boilerplate -- "we're not putting these on here because of _you_, they're on the list, see?" But that's also fair, about the classic questions.

Comment: Also, issues can be more complex: "what if a member of one minority finds some behaviour harmful, while a member of another minority is harmed by the absence of said behaviour?" "How do you decide when something crosses the 'be nice' line, and when it might not be very polite but it just isn't bad enough that it should be censured?" "If there's an argument over a sensitive subject, how do you balance civility against the strong emotions the argument elicits?" "How do you account for people coming from different cultures and different mother tongues?"

Comment: @Galastel I'd welcome this as an answer! When I said I was spitballing, I meant it -- my first cut is certainly not going to be the best way. It's a discussion -- I'm intending to hold a dialogue, not present a finished proposal.

Comment: BTW: you didn't include them, but there are two *mandatory* questions in every election: those were based on actual events at one time, and ended up being asked so frequently in the old moderator town halls that they got captured for this purpose. I would recommend a similar approach for identifying new topics that might be common across many sites.

Comment: The moderator has to walk a fine line: maintain and foster civility even in disagreements, but not act as a censor. Give space for opinions they might themselves disagree with, but make sure no user is made to feel unwelcome. In particular, they must be careful with what they themselves say, because they wield more power: I can argue a point with another user that I might be less comfortable arguing with a moderator. I guess I'd gear questions towards that line.

Comment: @Galastel There _are_ certain ideas that _are not permitted_ to be made on Stack Exchange. The people who make those arguments will feel unwelcome when their statements are removed, and there's not really much of a way to make them feel welcome, even if those removals are performed with empathy in our hearts. So I'm not sure that reply fully captures what's going on, at its core.

Comment: Well yeh, you're not supposed to support the KKK here. But there's plenty of greyer area. As an example, [christianity.se] has had to find a way to stay polite and civil between the many Christian denominations, some of which, I'm given to understand, consider others heretics.

Comment: @Galastel Those kinds of cases may be worth a site-specific question, since grey areas tend to appear pertinent to specific subject matter. I don't know of any way to ask about a case like that in a way that's generically applicable, but I absolutely welcome that input if you have ideas.

Comment: Yes, we can ask such questions as part of the electorate, but I wouldn't mind a couple of those questions being added to the standard questionnaire. (Maybe (1 or 3) and (4 or 5)?)

Comment: Is minoritized a word?  I agree with the objective.  4 & 5 are good.  1 - 3 seem too hypothetical.  It's informative to see how people respond to these; their thought process.  But, the answers will be mainly BS unless the person has actually been in the situation.  Nuances of the actual situation make a big difference.  There's also a problem of the questions being too open-ended and potentially interpreted in different ways, so you end up comparing apples to oranges.  It's better to ask what someone did in actual life when faced with something similar.  (cont'd)

Comment: If the person has never been a moderator, manager, teacher, or otherwise been in such a capacity, they don't really know what to do or what they might try.  People and situations are different from scenarios on paper.  Flip side, someone who has already handled such situations is likely better qualified, or at least people can better assess their fitness.

Comment: Question 5 is too unrelated, specific and personal for my taste. I personally can't think of a way to answer that with any relation to becoming a moderator on Stack Exchange.

Comment: I think that there is no other answer than "depends" from 1 in your second block. It heavily depends on what the representatives group says or demands. Say, (a) black people are telling that they are being victim of subtle racist comments and (b) charmander-loving people are complaining of losing too many pokémon battles to people having squirtles. I certainly would treat (a) as something very serious and (b) as something laughable, and I doubt that it would be different to any other sane person. This shows that your 1st question is too much generic and vague.

Comment: @VictorStafusa ...if someone answers that question as though the community were asking about charmander-loving people, I think that tells you all you need to know about that person's views on taking harms seriously.

Comment: @Aza That is just an example. Without further details, the question in unanswerable with something other than "depends".

Comment: @VictorStafusa That's valid. To that I'd say, these are unfinished questions, and that's something I'd want to see taken into account in any final copy, too.

Comment: This might not have the effect you intend it to have. Much of the community and especially on some sites the community in general is rather socially conservative compared to the rest. It may inadvertently have the effect of allowing people who like to dismiss such concerns to advertise their willingness to do so and gain votes that way.

Comment: @Magisch If that's a serious concern, that... seems like its own issue, because the clearly-stated aim of building a more inclusive network is deeply at odds with that fact.

Comment: @Aza That is correct and I've opined about this fact in the past. Much of the community across the network is global, and certain subjects have a much more socially conservative user base then you would think. Even SO (which, programming is a traditionally liberal field) probably is much more socially conservative then we think. I think asking this question on for instance a religion SE site would be an own goal as it would just allow people to soapbox the issue.

Comment: Even in the US, the breakdown of people who are acutely socially conservative on for instance the pronoun issue is quite high - 30 some % of democrats and 60 some % of republicans. If you extrapolate that to the rest of the world, especially keeping in mind that most of the world is *more* socially conservative then the US, you can probably see why making that a deciding factor in selecting moderators could backfire.

Comment: Judging from my experience, the majority of voters (who're site non-regulars) don't read the answers to the election questionnaires fully. For instance, I personally simply vote candidates based on their participation statistics and candidate score, on sites which I don't frequent. I doubt the change you're proposing will have the intended effect unless you drastically change the election procedure.

Comment: @Magisch I'm not sure what the other option is, here. If we want to start making progress towards acceptance, we need to know this information about the people we bring on. It will _suck_ when we realize someone's been elected who has _really damaging_ thoughts on a certain group. But pretending there isn't an issue is a major contributing factor to existing exclusion of minoritized groups. Should that really be swept under the rug?

Comment: @Aza no, of course not. But I think other issues need to be adressed before you can start doing that, and one of the points will have to be a clarified CoC. No need to give an additional opportunity to people to select candidates based on their beliefs when these contradict with the CoC. I think the actual solution here must be clearer requirements.

Comment: In a way, it shouldn't be a question whether you take the concerns of a user about harmful behavior seriously - that should just be a clearly communicated requirement for moderators, not a question.

Comment: @Magisch Obviously we can't allow moderators who don't follow the CoC, and if we don't think users can do that, _then_ what? I want to be up front that the logical conclusion is: free and democratic elections can't successfully pick candidates who can manage their bigotry in a healthy way. So we're slowly drifting into the territory of: "once we have clarified the CoC, we need to be able to veto candidates whose values don't match the ones we're seeking," which... is something I tentatively support, but is broader than this post's proposal.

Comment: @Aza "we need to be able to veto candidates whose values don't match the ones we're seeking" sure... but can you even achieve such thing? (regardless of the qualities in question) This sounds like situation when opening account in the bank they ask you to sign paper stating you will not use that account for criminal activities. I am sure that every criminal will straight out refuse.

Comment: @Dalija I'm actually unworried about practical implementation, believe it or not. If you ask someone questions that involve their character, people have a hard time _not_ being honest. There will always be ways to break the system but this, in my experience, has been fairly robust.

Comment: @Aza That is true.

Comment: The questions to be asked needn't be hard, they need to be relevant and answerable. Examples: *An SE employee introduces a policy change you disagree with. How do you react?* The question is quite relevant, the answer is, of course, easy (*I cheer, I applaud! I tell them it's the greatest innovation in the history of mankind!*). Or *Are you okay with SE employees sharing your name with the press and telling them how awful you are?* Simple yes or no question. Or *Is it more important to help minorities or to just create the impression of helping even if you don't?* Again, easy.